# Direct call from NodeJS to Kafka

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

What are the steps to complete a poll call directly from Javascript (NodeJS) to Kafka (not the HTTP endpoints or proxies), without a library? Examples would be wonderful, but even steps and directions are great.

So for instance, authentication, subscription, etc?

> PS: This is mostly to learn the internals of communicating with Kafka.

Comment: JavaScript in which context? Browser or Node.js?

Comment: Sorry, I meant NodeJS, I'll add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to Kafka (not the HTTP endpoints or proxies)

Kafka uses a custom TCP protocol, and not HTTP, so what you're looking for doesn't exist.

It'd be suggested to use a library rather than attempt to rewrite this TCP socket communication yourself, but if you wanted to, a completely blank slate would start with

```
const net = require('net');

const client = new net.Socket();
// Send a connection request to the server.
client.connect({ port: 9092, host: 'kafka' }), function() {
    console.log('TCP connection established with the server.');
    client.write(...); // some binary data matching Kafka spec
});

client.on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(`Data received from the server: ${chunk}.`); 
});

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Requested an end to the TCP connection');
});
```

Comment: I totally agree about using a library, as I mentioned however this is only for learning purposes and to make the Kafka black-box a bit more transparent.

Comment: FWIW implementing this yourself is hard and won't let you learn anything useful

Comment: @mim You could learn from source code of libraries - https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/tree/master/src/network

Comment: @OneCricketeer This is great, thanks for sharing the link, I was looking at the source code for a couple of other libraries but found them really bloated and hard to read, this one makes sense right off the bat!
```js
socket.on('data', onData)
  socket.on('end', onEnd)
  socket.on('error', onError)
  socket.on('timeout', onTimeout)
```